# Browserify require - inline way. How?

Tags: javascript, node.js, inline, browserify

Is there any possibility to include one file into another with Browserify?
I mean not standard Browserify behavior, but pasting one file into another in a specific place.

file1.js

```
console.log("abc");
```

file2.js

```
requirePaste("file1.js");
console.log("def");
```

output.js

```
console.log("abc");
console.log("def");
```

I need it for spreading an ES6 class into multiple files like this pattern:

```
ObjectManager.js
ObjectManager_Events.js
ObjectManager_Rendering.js
```

These files are about one class. So I can make something like this:

```
class ObjectManager {
    constructor() {
    }

    requirePaste("./ObjectManager_Events");
    requirePaste("./ObjectManager_Rendering");
}
```

**EDIT:**

I made a simple transform plugin for Browserify and it works great. There is one problem though it won't work with Watchify. this is because inline-required files aren't counted as being watched. Any idea on how to fix this?

```
const through = require('through2');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const regex = /require\([\s]*\/\*inline\*\/[\s]*"(.+)"\)/g;

function process(pathToFile, contents) {
  while ( (occurence = regex.exec(contents)) ) {
    contents = processOne(pathToFile, contents, occurence);
  }

  return contents;
}

function processOne(pathToFile, contents, occurence) {
  const dir = path.dirname(pathToFile);

  const includePath = occurence[1] + ".js";

  const range = [occurence.index, occurence.index+occurence[0].length-1];

  const pathToInnerFile = dir + "/" + includePath;
  var innerContents = fs.readFileSync(pathToInnerFile, 'utf8');

  innerContents = process(pathToInnerFile, innerContents);

  var output = "";

  output += contents.substring(0, range[0]);

  output += innerContents;

  output += contents.substring(range[1]+1);

  return output;
}

module.exports = function(pathToFile) {
  return through(
    function(buf, enc, next) {
      var result = process(pathToFile, buf.toString('utf8'));

      this.push(result);
      next();
    }
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

That did the trick:

Basically we inform Watchify about file by emiting 'file' event.

```
const includedFiles = [];

function process(pathToFile, contents) {
  includedFiles.push(pathToFile);

  while ( (occurence = regex.exec(contents)) ) {
    contents = processOne(pathToFile, contents, occurence);
  }

  return contents;
}

...

module.exports = function(pathToFile) {
  return through(
    function(buf, enc, next) {
      var result = process(pathToFile, buf.toString('utf8'));

      this.push(result);

      includedFiles.forEach((filePath) => this.emit("file", filePath));
      includedFiles.length = 0;

      next();
    }
  );
};
```